# AWX without docker

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install AXW for ansible on ubuntu but I would love to avoid using Docker. Is there any way to install it?

I saw that it is possible on CentOS 7 / RHEL 7 but I can find any solution for ubuntu.

Comment: Can you show where you see it's possible on Fedora. Per the official repo, ansible (Red Hat) lists docker as a prerequisite for installation. https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md

Comment: Sorry i so it was actually possible for CentOS 7 / RHEL 7, I found this tutorial and some others like this: http://yallalabs.com/devops/how-to-install-ansible-awx-without-docker-centos-7-rhel-7/

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. The article you linked says it's deprecated and points to the link I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Not officially, as per [Installation without containerisation (no docker, no openshift, no kubernetes)](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/989), but there are several other options for Debian.  It remains to be seen whether these will work with Ubuntu, or if there will need to be new features or forks to make it so:

- [A Debian package builder and pre-built package repository](https://github.com/valet-sh/awx-build-deb)
- [An attempt to make an official Debian package](https://github.com/valet-sh/awx-build-deb/issues/6)
- [An Ansible role](https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/cm42oj/a_new_role_to_install_awx_and_dependent_services/)

I would try the first one first.